# Solr filter on group

Tags: solr, grouping

I am looking for possibility to apply filter on group in Solr. It means that if at least one of documents in group isn't restricted by filter entire group should be displayed in search results. Moreover I need apply Solr filter on document to filter documents inside group. For example, I have following documents and group it by baseProductCode:

```
group test1
Test1VariantProduct1
    restrictedCountries: US
    type: ebook
    baseProductCode: test1
Test1VariantProduct2
    type: paperbook
    baseProductCode: test1
```

In this example I need to apply filter on document by restrictedCountries field and filter on group by type. It means that I would like to filter document with restricted countries and it could be implemented using fq=-countries=US. From the other hand I want to hide group from search result by type if all group documents are hidden. As result I want following cases will be valid:

1. Our system shouldn't display this group in search results for US country and ebook type.
2. Our system should display this group in search results for any other country and ebook type.

Could you please advice is it possible to implement it using Solr features?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using faceting to get your groups, they'll work with the set of documents *after* they've been filtered, so the groups won't be shown if there are no documents that matches from that group (i.e. you'd be faceting on `baseProductCode`).